# twists of algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

If $k$ is some field - for convenience, of characteristic 0 -, $\bar{k}$ is an alg. closure of $k$,  and $G$ is some $k$-algebraic group, one can define  a *twist* of $G$ to be some $k$-algebraic group $H$ such that $G \times_k \bar{k} \cong H \times_k \bar{k}$. My question is:

> Is there a *finite* field extension, say $K/k$, such that  $G \times_k K \cong H \times_k K$?

Comment: The isomorphism between these varieties over the algebraic closure is given by a finite number of polynomials whose coefficients lie in some finite field extension (the field extension generated by them).

Comment: @Pablo: Why a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The isomorphism $\phi \colon G \times_k \bar{k} \to H \times_k \bar{k}$ which exists by our assumption, is given by a finite set of ratinoal functions $f_1, \dots f_m \in \bar{k}(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $K$ be the field generated over $k$ by the coefficients of $f_1, \dots, f_m$ in $\bar{k}$. Then, $\phi$ is defined over $K$ so  $G \times_k K \cong H \times_k K$, and $K/k$ is a finite extension as it is generated by a finite set of algebraic elements over $k$.

The argument works for every field and for all varieties (not just algebraic groups).

It would be interesting to ask how arithmetically small can $K$ be taken in special cases. For example, if $G$ and $H$ are abelian varieties (maybe with some extra conditions) can we hope to be able to choose $K$ to be abelian/solvable over $k$?

For a very naive attempt see [Minimal fields of isomorphism for varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173514/minimal-fields-of-isomorphism-for-varieties)

Comment: If you want the $\bar k$ isomorphism of $G$ and $H$ to be an isomorphism as abelian varieties, i.e., respecting the group law, then the set of such $H$ (up to $k$-isomorphism) are classified by $H^1(\hbox{Gal}(\bar k/k),\hbox{Aut}(G))$. (Hmmm... Let's take char$(k)=0$.) Then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic over $K$ if and only if the restriction of the cocycle to $\hbox{Gal}(\bar k/K)$ is a coboundary. This gives a lot of tools to help answer your question.

Comment: @Pablo: The splitting field if often non-solvable. Consider $A=E^n$ for an elliptic curve $E$ over $k$ that is not geometrically CM. The Aut-scheme of $A$ is the constant $k$-group ${\rm{GL}}_n(\mathbf{Z})$, which is also the Aut-scheme of ${\rm{GL}}_1^n$, so the sets of isomorphism classes of $k$-forms of $A$ and of $n$-dimensional $k$-tori are in natural bijection. For a finite Galois extension $k'/k$, the Weil-restricted $k$-torus ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}({\rm{GL}}_1)$ splits over a finite separable $F/k$ if and only if $k'$ embeds $F$ over $k$, so enough that there is such $k'/k$ non-solvable.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: The Isom-scheme between two abelian varieties over an arbitrary field is etale since even the Hom-scheme is etale (tangent space at identity vanishes by rigidity of homomorphisms between abelian schemes, applied over the dual numbers). Hence, if two abelian varieties over $k$ becomes isomorphic over a (perhaps huge) extension field then their *etale* Isom-scheme is non-empty and thus has a point over a finite separable extension. Thus, the Galois cohomology set ${\rm{H}}^1(k_s/k,{\rm{Aut}}_{k_s}(A_{k_s}))$ indeed classifies isomorphism classes of "$k$-forms" of $A$ in any sense.

Comment: @Pablo: Just to clarify, when I wrote "The splitting field is often non-solvable" I should have said "Generally there is no solvable splitting field" (the point being that generally there is not a unique minimal splitting field for a cohomology class with coefficients in a non-constant group, so it is not meaningful to speak of "the" splitting field in such cases).

Comment: @user74230 thank you for your explanation. What if the abelian varieties are assumed simple? For example, I think that elliptic curves which are isomorphic over the algebraic closure, become isomorphic over an abelian extension.

Comment: @Pablo: Elliptic curves are a bad guide to higher dimensions; their automorphism groups are too easy. The Aut-scheme of an elliptic curve is the constant group $\langle -1\rangle$ when $j \ne 0, 1728$, so Isom-schemes are $\mu_2$-torsors when non-empty, so separable quadratic extensions suffice. But if $j=0, 1728$ then the Aut-scheme could be non-constant (e.g., $\mu_4$ or $\mu_6$), so there is no reason for abelian extensions to split the Isom-scheme as a torsor. Absolutely simple abelian varieties can have huge non-commutative geometric Aut-groups, so abelian extensions have no special role.

Comment: @user74230 so for elliptic curves it is possible to have no solvable extension over which they become isomorphic? Maybe there is some way to say that abelian varieties become isomorphic over a field whose discriminant is not too big or that we know something about the splitting of primes in it.

Comment: @Pablo: I didn't make any such statement -- I only referred to abelian extensions. A torsor for a cyclic finite etale group splits over a solvable extension (coefficients split over an abelian extension since Aut of a cyclic group is commutative, and the resulting cohomology class with constant coefficients splits over a further abelian extension), so for elliptic curves away from $j=0, 1728$ in char. 2 and 3 solvable is enough. Your speculation for AV's (meant to assume absolute simplicity?) is probably false, due to the complexity of Aut-groups; do you have a reason behind your guess?

Comment: @user74230 my claim about absolutely simple abelian varieties is indeed a speculation, which may be completely wrong. There is a reason to hope that under additional assumptions something of this kind may be not obviously false. I will support my speculation by a related conjecture: Let $V/\mathbb{Q}$ be a (geometrically irreducible) variety. Then $V$ has a rational point in a solvable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user74230 note that in the conjecture "generally" you will have no solvable points, but still no counterexample is known and for genus $1$ curves there is a proof (by Wiles). I just think about the Aut-scheme as the variety $V$.

Comment: @Pablo: Personally I don't believe the "conjecture" about solvable points on geometrically integral varieties/curves, and it is more a "question" or "guess" than a conjecture (e.g., I am not aware of any good reason for believing it -- the case of genus 1 is too special. It is just something that would be very useful if it were true, and I believe this is the only reason that Taylor raised it.)  Anyway, for the situation with isomorphisms of abelian varieties we're dealing with torsors for *etale* groups, so that conjecture/guess doesn't provide guidance for what to expect.

Comment: Regarding the conjecture that the maximal solvable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is "pseudo algebraically closed", definitely it fails for global *function* fields (as opposed to global number fields).  I believe that Ambrus Pal has an article with counterexamples.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Really?!? Where is such an article to be found? I know he did some work related to this problem over some other fields, but I never heard of such counterexamples being found over global function fields. That would be really great!!

Comment: @user74230 a little search revealed http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~apal4/publ/solvpoint.pdf the results of which are very interesting (to say the least).

Comment: @user74230: "Where is such an article to be found?"  I was wrong -- sorry!  Ambrus Pal proves that there are function fields of surfaces over finite fields whose maximal solvable extension is not pseudo algebraically closed.  I misremembered his result as applying to function fields of curves over finite fields, but I was wrong.  Sorry!

Comment: @JasonStarr: OK, thanks for checking on that.